# Comparing analog signal from Electret mic with samples

Tags: embedded, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, tensorflow-lite, mcu

I'm working on a mini home automation system that can basically turn on/off and as well change the color using voice commands. I've generated tensorflow audio samples. But how do I compare this samples with the signals received from Electret mic in my code to perform the task I wanted?

I've researched about audio libraries in C/C++ that can do this but I can find any.

Comment: The question is too broad and unclear which part of this project you are struggling with.  You seem to have a rather simplistic idea if what is required.  I suggest that you should start by solving the speech recognition problem independent of your embedded system and understand the principles.  You might for example start from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio. Then worry about how you can embed that, for example https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers.

Comment: ... Then you need to deal with the signal acquisition and processing https://www.google.com/search?q=stm32+microphone+audio+acquisition&oq=stm32+audio+aquisition